# Fatal: input format error for git mktree command

Tags: git, windows-10, git-bash

I am learning GIT using GIT Bash on Windows 10. And I was learning to create a GIT tree object. So, what I did was made two blobs of the following hashes:

```
4400aae52a27341314f423095846b1f215a7cf08
b7aec520dec0a7516c18eb4c68b64ae1eb9b5a5e
```

Both blobs have the permission 100644. Now I made a file on Desktop as temp-tree.txt and added the following blobs with their respective parameters as:

```
100644 blob b7aec520dec0a7516c18eb4c68b64ae1eb9b5a5e file1.txt
100644 blob 4400aae52a27341314f423095846b1f215a7cf08 file2.txt
```

Saved it as temp-tree.txt. Now, in the GIT Bash terminal in the master folder I gave the following command:

```
cat ../temp-tree.txt | git mktree
```

which showed as:

```
fatal: input format error: 100644 blob b7aec520dec0a7516c18eb4c68b64ae1eb9b5a5e file1.txt
```

Kindly suggest to me how to correct it. I used Udemy's Bodgan's Complete Git and GitHub guide course.
If you want I can give you the screenshot of that part. But, I am refraining from adding it now as it may not work for some render. Thank you for your time and effort.

Update 1: I tried using TAB. But, it gave this as output:

```
cat ../temp-tree.txt
100644 blob b7aec520dec0a7516c18eb4c68b64ae1eb9b5a5e    file1.txt
100644 blob 4400aae52a27341314f423095846b1f215a7cf08    file2.txt

cat ../temp-tree.txt | git mktree
fatal: input format error: (blank line only valid in batch mode)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr: use a tab between the hash and the filename, and make sure that the file has Unix-style (`\n`) line endings.

[`git mktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mktree)'s manual page indicates that it:

> Reads standard input in non-recursive ls-tree output format

And [`git ls-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree)'s manual page indicates that this format is:

> `<mode> SP <type> SP <object> TAB <file>`

Your file looks like it has a `SP` (space) between the `<object>` and the `<file>`, not a `TAB`.

---

You also say that you "created the file" but do not provide additional details.  If you created it with - say - Notepad, then the file almost certainly has DOS-style (`\r\n`) line endings.  git will not tolerate this.

You'll need to convert this file to have Unix style line endings using a tool like `dos2unix` (included with Git for Windows) or a text editor (in vim, you would `:set ff=unix` and then save the file and exit with `:wq`).

Comment: Okay. I try again using TAB.

Comment: I tried it but it gives : `fatal: input format error: (blank line only valid in batch mode)`

Comment: This is the cat output: `cat ../temp-tree.txt
100644 blob b7aec520dec0a7516c18eb4c68b64ae1eb9b5a5e    file1.txt
100644 blob 4400aae52a27341314f423095846b1f215a7cf08    file2.txt`

Comment: Wait, when you say you _created the file_, how did you do that?  Importantly: **what kind of line endings does this file have**?

Comment: i created using nano and one next line (enter to next line) is there

Comment: @jayant98 paste the contents of `hexdump -C temp-tree.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

I created a tree by typing in: cat ../temp-tree.txt | git mktree -z. It worked! I realized that the output is a 2 number "file" instead of a char and a number or vice-versa.

IS THE STANDARD APPROACH FOR BLOBS: 6b,c7 ?? I guess not.

Once you use the -z flag, the tree object will begin with numbers: 56 or 42.

THE TREE is definately there. However, when you type in git read-tree + the hash which is 56a7(for example), it throws an error. I guess I moved 1 step forward. The tricky part remains on the staging area?

Hope my answer moves on with the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space at the top of your content.
There should be no space at the top and at the bottom of your entered information.

[image: code without space at top and bottom]

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same issue, what I have done is create two files in working directory named `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`, commit into staging area and git created tree object for me using those files.

Once the hash is generated, I deleted both the files in working directory and using `git read-tree` to move files from git repository to staging area, and using command `git checkout-index -a` to moves files from staging area to working directory.

Why I am approaching this solution is, agenda here is to create tree object in git repo and move files from git repo to staging and working directory, if we are facing issue to create tree object, then allow git to create object for us, and apply the things what we learned on git.

Hope my answer answered your question

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue, when file was edited using my vs code editor :

on observing output of command

```
od -bc <filename>
```

, tab was replaced by 4 spaces which was causing the issue where as when file was edited using notepad or notepad++, tab was replaced by \t and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

try like this it works.

step 1:

```
echo "100644 blob b7aec520dec0a7516c18eb4c68b64ae1eb9b5a5e file1.txt" > temp-tree.txt
```

step 2:

```
echo "100644 blob 4400aae52a27341314f423095846b1f215a7cf08 file2.txt" >> temp-tree.txt
```

step 3:

```
cat ../temp-tree.txt | git mktree
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I noticed that it gives this error because before saving I pressed space and went to the next line. To solve, go on nano and just press backspace to go back to the previous line.
After trying again

```
cat ../temp-tree.txt | git mktree
```

it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following

cat $HOME/Desktop/temp-tree.txt
100644 blob 4400aae52a27341314f423095846b1f215a7cf08    file1.txt
100644 blob b7aec520dec0a7516c18eb4c68b64ae1eb9b5a5e    file2.txt%

cat $HOME/Desktop/temp-tree.txt|git mktree
8c67c72539e729ff98793e782d7d3c642f31d297

Don't know why needs a % at the end. What I did to figure out this was to access an old Github repo, run the command git ls-tree -r HEAD and copied the output from the command console into Sublime. I then replaced the values, saved the file, back to the course repo and cat the file. When I did that, it appeared the % at then end (which was never shown in Sublime).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).